# I called a mosque garbage once

Tags: masjid, kufr

So around 2.5 years ago or maybe 3 years ago I went on a trip to the mosque and it wasn’t big or anything but it was peaceful and now I wouldn’t dare to say something like that becuase  And I was very ignorant in this years and I regret it. I suffer from waswas and I used to tell myself that I would pray in any mosque no matter the size. I told my friends that the mosque we won’t to was katchra (in Arabic) in English it means garbage basically and now I am worried that it took me out of the pale of Islam and I said it to fit in or to seem that my standards are high you know like luxury and I didn’t really intended to disrespect my religion and I am worried I disbelieved after I believed now however I am much different. Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Allah knows your intentions. Relax and have faith that Allah knows best. Not everything needs to be written.